# plotting time in hh:mm:ss format on the x axis

Tags: datetime, timestamp

I have an issue, which I feel should be really easy to solve, however I am unable to figure it out.

I have two arrays of equal length, one containing some measurement values and another one containing the time stamps of this measurements as strings in the form of hh:mm:ss (for example: `time = ['09:17:12', '09:17:13', '09:17:17', ..., '12:49:02']`. The time stamps are not equally separated in time, sometimes they differ by a second, sometimes by 5 seconds. Both arrays are very long - around 100 000 entries.

I would like to plot the measurement values on the y axis against the time stamp values on the x axis. Additionally I would like the formatter on the x axis to show the time every hour (or two hours) in order to avoid overlapping.

I've spent quite a long time trying to figure out how to do it, and I assume it should be fairly straightforward, however I am unable to do it. I guess it should involve `datetime`, `date2num`, as well as fiddling with the x axis formatter and locator. If anyone has any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what language / packages are you using, Python & matplotlib? pandas?